# how to get the sum from both column in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

03:43:50 CALL totalbill (50020, @totalbill) Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'totalcount' in 'field list' 0.000 sec

Answer (score 0):

Is totalcount a column in your database table? Otherwise, you need to create a variable to store that information.

You should store any values that you want to run a calculation on into a local variable and then do your arithmetic. You need to take a look at how you are executing that select statement.